# How can I decompiling IL code of .net framework

Tags: c#, .net, decompiling, cil, ildasm

I want to investigate IL code of most .net framework library classes. Is it possible? I am trying to decompiling some dll (e.g.: System.Treading), and I only see signature of the functions. Then I go to mscorlib.dll and see only manifest. There is a way to see the real code?

Comment: have you checked IlSpy  https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy. Free and open source and for VS 2017/2019 (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.ILSpy)

Comment: You have to watch out for the reference assemblies, they are special and don't contain any code.  Best way is to pick the assembly that is actually used in a program, stored in the GAC, navigate to c:\windows\microsoft.net\assembly

Comment: @YVEF no problemo, hope that helps :)

Comment: Some background info on reference assemblies, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-referenced-assemblies-7d752d92c18c When you only see signature of the functions, you are using the wrong assemblies like Hans Passant commented.

Answer (score 3):

You can use .NET Reflector (commercial but very good):

https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/

You can open a .net assembly with it (.exe or .dll).

So you can also directly browse .NET Framework assemblies by selecting the framework version.

Select view IL or other language such as C# or VB code and it is done.

There is also for example this free tool (slow, very slow):

https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to study the implementation of .Net classes. I suggest you use the reference code provided by Microsoft.

The main advantage of using the reference code, is that you can see the comments and other elements that will not be added to IL (like #define).

[Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

To study the effect of certain C# constructs on the generated IL, I would suggest using SharpLib.

[SharpLib](https://sharplab.io/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I know about referencecode, but it does not contain everything that i need.

Answer (score 2):

Personnaly to decompile IL code i use ILspy , it's lightweight tool and easy to use .

you can found it in the link below :

https://sourceforge.net/projects/ilspyportable/

Best Regards .

Comment: ILSpy is indeed a very good tool and it's free, however the project is not on Source Forge anymore, it's now on GitHub: https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy